# Java android stop service

Tags: java, android

I can not stop (kill) my intent service. This is how I started my service:

```
 private void startService(Class<?> service, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, Bundle extras) {
        if (!UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED) {
            Intent startService = new Intent(this, service);
            if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {
                Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                for (String key : keys) {
                    String extra = extras.getString(key);
                    startService.putExtra(key, extra);
                }
            }
            startService(startService);
        }
        Intent bindingIntent = new Intent(this, service);
        bindService(bindingIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
```

And this is my intent service :

```
public class UsbService extends Service {

    public static final String ACTION_USB_READY = "pl.gps.connectivityservices.USB_READY";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_ATTACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DETACHED = "android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED = "pl.gps.usbservice.USB_NOT_SUPPORTED";
    public static final String ACTION_NO_USB = "pl..gps.usbservice.NO_USB";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED = "pl.gps.usbservice.USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED = "pl.gps.usbservice.USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED = "pl.gps.usbservice.USB_DISCONNECTED";
    public static final String ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING = "pl.gps.connectivityservices.ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING";
    public static final String ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING = "pl.gps.connectivityservices.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING";
    public static final int MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT = 1;
    private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
    private static final int BAUD_RATE = 9600; // BaudRate. Change this value if you need
    public static boolean SERVICE_CONNECTED = false;

    private IBinder binder = new UsbBinder();

    private Context context;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private UsbManager usbManager;
    private UsbDevice device;
    private UsbDeviceConnection connection;
    private UsbSerialDevice serialPort;

    private boolean serialPortConnected;
    /*
     *  Data received from serial port will be received here. Just populate onReceivedData with your code
     *  In this particular example. byte stream is converted to String and send to UI thread to
     *  be treated there.
     */
    String date = "";

    public static boolean check(String s) {
        if (s.contains("$GNRMC")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    private UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback mCallback = new UsbSerialInterface.UsbReadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedData(byte[] arg0) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(700);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                String data = new String(arg0, "UTF-8");

                if (mHandler != null) {
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_FROM_SERIAL_PORT, data).sendToTarget();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver usbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)) {
                boolean granted = arg1.getExtras().getBoolean(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                if (granted) // User accepted our USB connection. Try to open the device as a serial port
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                    arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                    serialPortConnected = true;
                    new ConnectionThread().run();
                } else // User not accepted our USB connection. Send an Intent to the Main Activity
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION_NOT_GRANTED);
                    arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED)) {
                if (!serialPortConnected)
                    findSerialPortDevice(); // A USB device has been attached. Try to open it as a Serial port
            } else if (arg1.getAction().equals(ACTION_USB_DETACHED)) {
                // Usb device was disconnected. send an intent to the Main Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DISCONNECTED);
                arg0.sendBroadcast(intent);
                serialPortConnected = false;
                serialPort.close();
            }
        }
    };

    /*
     * onCreate will be executed when service is started. It configures an IntentFilter to listen for
     * incoming Intents (USB ATTACHED, USB DETACHED...) and it tries to open a serial port.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context = this;
        serialPortConnected = false;
        UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED = true;
        setFilter();
        usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        findSerialPortDevice();
    }



    /* MUST READ about services
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html
     * http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html
     */
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        UsbService.SERVICE_CONNECTED = false;
    }

    /*
     * This function will be called from MainActivity to write data through Serial Port
     */
    public void write(byte[] data) {
        if (serialPort != null)
            serialPort.write(data);
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler mHandler) {
        this.mHandler = mHandler;
    }

    private void findSerialPortDevice() {

        // This snippet will try to open the first encountered usb device connected, excluding usb root hubs
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices1 = new HashMap<String, UsbDevice>();
        usbDevices1.clear();

        if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
            boolean keep = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
                device = entry.getValue();
                int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
                int devicePID = device.getProductId();



                if (deviceVID == 1659 && devicePID == 8963) {
                    // There is a device connected to our Android device. Try to open it as a Serial Port.
                    requestUserPermission();
                    keep = false;

                    if (!keep)
                        break;
                }
            }


            if (!keep) {
                // There is no USB devices connected (but usb host were listed). Send an intent to MainActivity.
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NO_USB);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        } else {
            // There is no USB devices connected. Send an intent to MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_NO_USB);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    public void  unReg(){
     //   if(usbReceiver != null)
      //  unregisterReceiver(usbReceiver);
    }

    private void setFilter() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_DETACHED);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_ATTACHED);
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, filter);
    }

    private void requestUserPermission() {
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
        usbManager.requestPermission(device, mPendingIntent);
    }

    public class UsbBinder extends Binder {
        public UsbService getService() {
            return UsbService.this;
        }
    }


    private class ConnectionThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            serialPort = UsbSerialDevice.createUsbSerialDevice(device, connection);
            if (serialPort != null) {
                if (serialPort != null && serialPort.open()) {
                    serialPort.setBaudRate(BAUD_RATE);
                    serialPort.setDataBits(UsbSerialInterface.DATA_BITS_8);
                    serialPort.setStopBits(UsbSerialInterface.STOP_BITS_1);
                    serialPort.setParity(UsbSerialInterface.PARITY_NONE);
                    serialPort.setFlowControl(UsbSerialInterface.FLOW_CONTROL_OFF);
                    serialPort.read(mCallback);


                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_READY);
                    context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else {
                    if (serialPort instanceof CDCSerialDevice) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CDC_DRIVER_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_DEVICE_NOT_WORKING);
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_USB_NOT_SUPPORTED);
                context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try di this :

```
unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
    unbindService(usbConnection);

    if (timer != null)
        timer.cancel();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, UsbService.class);
    stopService(intent);
```

But my  intent service steal is working. I try did whis when I destroyed my activity in which I created this service but when this activity is destroyed in logs I see that all the time this intent service is steel working

Comment: Is `mUsbReceiver` different from `usbReceiver`?

Comment: @greeble31 no is this same

Comment: I'm a bit confused, then. `usbReceiver` is `private`, so how did you get it into `mUsbReceiver`? In what function is your `unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver)` call located? Please edit your question to clarify.